# SQL Server: get expression error with this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

Table:

```
create table produts_1164 
(
    product_id int,
    new_price int,
    change_date date
);

insert into produts_1164 
values (1, 20, '2019-08-14'),
       (2, 50, '2019-08-14'),
       (1, 30, '2019-08-15'),
       (1, 35, '2019-08-16'),
       (2, 65, '2019-08-17'),
       (3, 20, '2019-08-18');
```

Question: write a SQL query to find the prices of all products on 2019-08-16. Assume the price of all products before any change is 10.

Here is my solution:

```
select product_id, new_price as price 
from products
where (product_id, change_date) in (select product_id, max(change_date) 
                                    from products 
                                    where change_date <= '2019-08-16' 
                                    group by product_id)
union
select product_id, 10 as price 
from products
where product_id not in (select distinct product_id 
                         from products 
                         where change_date <= '2019-08-16');
```

But I get this error:

> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','. (4145) (SQLExecDirectW)

Any idea of this? Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can have multiple column comparing to an IN in sqlserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you want the prices for *all* products at a given point in time, including those that did not change before that date (with a default of 20), you need to look across all rows (not only those before the target date).

I would use `outer apply` here:

```
select p.product_id, coalesce(p1.new_price, 20), p1.change_date
from (select distinct product_id from produts_1164) p
outer apply (
    select top 1 * 
    from produts_1164 p1 
    where p1.product_id = p.product_id and p1.change_date <= '2019-08-16'
    order by p1.change_date desc
) p1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8519f14e76aed67216b838446a18e35e)**:

```
product_id | (No column name) | change_date
---------: | ---------------: | :----------
         1 |               35 | 2019-08-16 
         2 |               50 | 2019-08-14 
         3 |               20 | null
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*
from produts_1164 p
where p.date = (select max(p2.date)
                from produts_1164 p2
                where p2.product_id = p.product_id and
                      p2.change_date <= '2019-08-16'
               );
```

Or window functions:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product_id order by change_date desc) as seqnum
      from produts_1164 p
      where p.change_date <= '2019-08-16'
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```